# Reformulate linear program as semidefinite program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

We consider the linear program

$$\min_{x \in R^n} \{c^Tx \mid a_1^Tx \le b_1, a_2^Tx \le b_2\}$$

where $c, a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb R^n$ and $b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb R$ are given.
Now we need to reformulate this LP as an SDP.

Can someone help with this task? Thank you!

Comment: What is m?  (in $\min_{m \in \mathbb{R}^n}$)

Comment: @IgorD. sorry, should be x, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI) instead of the two linear inequalities

$$\begin{bmatrix} b_1 - \mathrm a_1^{\top} \mathrm x & 0\\ 0 & b_2 - \mathrm a_2^{\top} \mathrm x\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_2$$

Take a look at [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) for positive semidefiniteness.

Comment: Forgive me for beign stupid, but what is $O_2$?

Comment: $\rm O_2$ is the $2 \times 2$ zero matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put it in the form
$$
\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} c^T x
$$
$$
s.b. F_0 + \sum_i x_i F_i \succeq 0
$$
where $F_i,\, i=0...$ are symmetric matrices of order $2$.

Take
$$
F_0=
\begin{pmatrix} 
 b_1 &0 \\
0 & b_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and 
$$
F_i=
\begin{pmatrix} 
 -a_{1i} &0 \\
0 & -a_{2i}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a_j=(a_{j1},\ldots a_{jn})^T, \; j=1,2$